# Solving Delay PDE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, integral-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I'm trying to numerically solve the following delay PDE:

$$
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}  f(x,t) = \int_{x+1}^\infty f(y, t) \hspace{0.2em} dy
$$

given the initial conditions

$$
    f(x,0) = 0, \hspace{1em} \lim_{t \to 0} \int_0^\infty x f(x,t) \hspace{0.1em} dx = 1
$$

I tried `NDSolve`:

```
pde := D[f[x, t], t] == Integrate[f[y, t], {y, x + 1, Infinity}]
ic = {f[x, 0] == 0, Integrate[x*f[x, 0], {x, 0, Infinity}] == 1}
NDSolve[{pde, ic}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

but it doesn't support delay PDEs (`NDSolve: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve`). I did see some creative answers to other posts with delay PDEs, so I was hoping that there might be a clever workaround in my case too? Thanks.

**Note:** Just for clarity, the equation that I'm ultimately interested in numerically solving is equation 2 from [Krapivsky (1992)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01053786). There is an analytic solution outlined there, but that fails if I modify the PDE in any way (which I would like to do), so I'd like a numerical solution. I figured that posting that full piecewise equation might be off-putting, hence putting a reduced version above.

Comment: Usually with integro-differential equations like yours, you should differentiate them to convert them into (hopefully) more tractable normal DEs.

Comment: What's the meaning of `dx`in the second condition?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Sorry, that was supposed to be before the equals sign

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I think that it simply is misplaced.  Should follow $f(x, t)$ instead.  See the code for `ic`.

Comment: @Ted I am afraid the two conditions perhaps  contradict each other ? Substitute f[x,0]==0 into the left hand side of condition two!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann There's a jump from 0 to when `t` goes from 0 to being slightly greater than 0

Comment: @Ted It looks like there are two(!) initial conditions!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, there are 2 initial conditions. Sorry for any confusion, see the note on my updated post for the origin of the equation.

Comment: @Ted Perhaps you can find an iterative numerical solution using `NestList` ?

Comment: Maybe let $f(x,t)=b e^{ax+bt}$ with Re(a)<0 and $b=-\frac{e^{a}}{a}$.  Keep in mind PDE is linear so $a$ and $b$ can be complex and real and imaginary parts of f(x,t) are solutions.  Maybe can fit to your conditions.

Comment: Executing `pde = D[f[x, t], t] == Integrate[f[y, t], {y, x + 1, Infinity}];pde1 = D[pde, x]; ic = {f[x, 0] == 0, 
  Integrate[x*f[x, 0], {x, 0, Infinity}] == 1};sol=NDSolve[{pde1,ic},f,{x,0,1},{t,0,1}]`, one sees "NDSolve::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve." and the returned input.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, so we have the derivative (df/dxdt = -f[1 + x, t]), as suggested by J. M. in the first comment. Any idea where to go from there?

Comment: Seems to me if we have $\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{t}}=-f(x+1,t)$, how can this be numerically solved in the interval $0\leq x\leq 1$, $0\leq t\leq 1$ as stated by Ted above,  without knowing as initial conditions,  $f(x,t)$ in the region $1\leq x\leq 2$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$?

Comment: @Ted Is the question still relevant? What would be an examplary function, which fulfills both initial conditions? Sudden change `f[0+]`doesn't explain this!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes the question is still relevant. I've updated my original question with a link to a paper by Krapivsky, where he has the same initial conditions.

Comment: @Ted What would be an examplary function `f[x,t]` which fullfills both `ic`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The solution to Equation 2 in that aforementioned paper is `f[x_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2*Integrate[\[Tau]*Exp[-2 * Integrate[(1 - Exp[-u])/u, {u, 0, t}]]*Exp[-x*\[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}], x < 1}, {t^2 *Exp[-2 * Integrate[(1 - Exp[-u])/u, {u, 0, t}]]*Exp[-(x - 1)*t], x > 1}}]`. This satisfies both `ic`

Comment: @Ted This function isn't continuous at `x==1`, is this behavior intended?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, this is intended. `f` measures the density of gaps/voids of length `x` on an infinite length line during a random sequential adsorption process. Can be though of as parking unit-length non-overlapping "cars" on a road